# Easiest way of creating a window in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I'm working on a small personal project where I'd like to port some amateur game project of mine from Java to C#.

I've run into a problem with C# when it comes to pragmatically creating a window.

Research and some experimentation led me to find the System.Windows.Forms.Form class, but that's meant for a typical UI (buttons, controls etc.) and not rendering. (I was going to just add a bitmap element to the container within the form but I think it'll be far too slow as it wasn't designed for this.)

The next thing I found was the System.Windows.Window class, which is simpler than the Form class above, I could append a XAML canvas to it and draw to that. The problem I'm running into is requiring a thread of type STA to run the window which makes things more complicated.

I there any straightforward window creation in C# for 2d graphical applications?

I'm purposely avoiding XNA and OpenGL/DirectX as I want to learn as much as possible and try and do most of the heavy lifting myself.

Comment: It depends on what type of project you are making. I.e it makes little sense to use winforms dialogs in a wpf et al. Start by picking a framework, and then research how people show dialogs in that framework. Note: it makes little sense to have a conventional dialog in xna since the games can port to wp8 and xbox

Comment: I don't want to use a framework, that's the point. I'm trying to find the simplest way to create a window and then pragmatically manipulate the pixels in it. In java I can do that very easily with a JFrame and painting an image to it 30 times a second, for example.

The problem being that all the window classes in c# seem geared more towards forms, buttons and normal applications.

Comment: At some point you will be using a framework though, even if it comes from [`WindowsGDI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx) but at some point you will need help from the os. A lot of the frameworks just make this *a lot* simpler.

Comment: Any suggestions off the top of your head given the requirements?

Comment: Well C# is too high level to effectively deal with the drawing (in my opinion), I've had to make a graphics renderer in gdi+ before and doing that does teach you loads about what actually gets done behind the scenes but honestly I'd just use whats readily available (xna/unity/udk etc) and make your own renderer as a side project, main reason being that gdi doesn't use the graphics card (of course you could make a renderer in opengl/d3d but you dont learn as much)